# Integrate userVoice SDK with meteor

Tags: meteor, uservoice

I have userVoice.js

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
  // Include the UserVoice JavaScript SDK (only needed once on a page)
  UserVoice=window.UserVoice||[];(function(){var uv=document.createElement('script');uv.type='text/javascript';uv.async=true;uv.src='//widget.uservoice.com/cOADa8czIXBWdvlpMDtTVg.js';var s=document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(uv,s)})();

  //
  // UserVoice Javascript SDK developer documentation:
  // https://www.uservoice.com/o/javascript-sdk
  //

  //var feedbackEmail = Meteor.user().emails[0].address;

  // Set colors
  UserVoice.push(['set', {
    accent_color: '#448dd6',
    trigger_color: 'white',
    trigger_background_color: 'rgba(46, 49, 51, 0.6)'
  }]);

  // Identify the user and pass traits
  // To enable, replace sample data with actual user traits and uncomment the line
  UserVoice.push(['identify', {
    //email:      feedbackEmail, // User’s email address
    //name:       'John Doe', // User’s real name
    //created_at: 1364406966, // Unix timestamp for the date the user signed up
    //id:         123, // Optional: Unique id of the user (if set, this should not change)
    //type:       'Owner', // Optional: segment your users by type
    //account: {
    //  id:           123, // Optional: associate multiple users with a single account
    //  name:         'Acme, Co.', // Account name
    //  created_at:   1364406966, // Unix timestamp for the date the account was created
    //  monthly_rate: 9.99, // Decimal; monthly rate of the account
    //  ltv:          1495.00, // Decimal; lifetime value of the account
    //  plan:         'Enhanced' // Plan name for the account
    //}
  }]);

  // Add default trigger to the bottom-right corner of the window:
  // UserVoice.push(['addTrigger', { mode: 'contact', trigger_position: 'bottom-right' }]);

  // Or, use your own custom trigger:
  UserVoice.push(['addTrigger', '#submitFeedback', { mode: 'contact' }]);

  // Autoprompt for Satisfaction and SmartVote (only displayed under certain conditions)
  UserVoice.push(['autoprompt', {}]);
});
```

It runs sometimes but then sometimes I get a client error:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null
```

Wondering if I'm running the script wrong. Also not sure how the additional scripts load up in Meteor and in what order

Answer (score 1):

Just implemented uservoice on my meteor app, similarly to your idea, but I think you forgot to uncomment the user info.

```
Deps.autorun(function() {
 var user = Meteor.user();
 if(user) {
   //uservoice code
 }
```

And now the stuff to indentify the user:

```
UserVoice.push(['identify', {
     email:      user.profile.email, // User’s email address
     name:       user.fullName(), // User’s real name
     id:         user._id, // Optional: Unique id of the user (if set, this should not change)
     type:       'user', // Optional: segment your users by type       
}]);
```

It's working so far.